# Rails authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic always return Completed 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curb

I'm trying to secure my API service using `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic`, i have tried in GET and POST method it return true, so i can store/fetch data from API but when i'm trying to update value, the rails always return false and the terminal looks like this:

```
Filter chain halted as :authenticate rendered or redirected
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I was wondering why it always failed to authenticate on update/PUT/PATCH method ?

here is the complete method to authenticate my API service:

```
def authenticate
  puts "here 1"
  if authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Qontak') do |username, password|
      puts "here 2"
      @user = User.find_by(public_key: username, private_key: password)
    end
  else
    puts "here 3"
    render json: {message: 'Unauthorized'}
  end
  puts "here 4"
end
```